# Is it possible to make geany also highlight unknown HTML-tags?

Tags: html, polymer, syntax-highlighting, geany

I'm currently playing around with Polymer and then you often use custom tags, such as `<paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="...">...</paper-icon-button></code>`. But geany doesn't highlight them like normal HTML-tags (bold blue for `<div` and `>`, bold darkblue for `class=`, medium green for `"label"`) – The whole text is displayed in medium blue.

Here's a demonstration of both types of tags:

[image: Heres a demonstration of both types of tags]

Now my question: Is it possible to make geany also highlight unknown HTML-tags? Or, can you install another syntax highlighter that solves my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add keywords to a custom filetypes.html.

Copy this file from your Geany-installation-dir/data to your .config-folder of Geany -- on Linux this will be somewhere at ~/.config/geany/filedefs ; on Windows it will be somewhere like this C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\geany\filedefs and add your new tag as a keyword.

The file is a normal key-value with section, so you will find something like that inside:

```
[keywords]
html=a abbr acronym address applet area b base basefont bdo big blockquote ....
```

That's the point you need to add your new keywords. the current upstream version of the file can be found at https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/master/data/filedefs/filetypes.html

Comment: Well, I simply added a ` ^ ` to the list so every tag is being formatted. Works fine, thanks!

(In order to avoid mis-formatting on other tags, ` template ^iron- ^paper- ` would be a nicer solution, but as soon as you add custom elements, you have to add them manually to the list.)

Answer (score 0):

The other solution can be adding new filetype and using it in such way there will be no need to harm your original `filetype.html`. Adding custom filetype is just piece of cake and will not take so much efforts and time. You can check documentation of  [custom filetype](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#custom-filetypes) in geany. You will just need to copy and paste filetype.html and change a few lines in new file inside geany/data.

```
 cp filetypes.html filetypes.Foo.conf
```

Change keywords and modify filetype_extesions.conf